# WordEditor Insert HTML from string

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

Working on a word document to which I need to add some text in HTML. I am able to load HTML form a file using the below code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();
// Loading of Content
// ...
Range wdRange = doc.Range(0, doc.Characters.Count);
wdRange.InsertFile(FileName: @"C:\temp\MyTextInHtml.html", Attachment: false);
```

The issue is that my HTML content is in a string and not in a file:

```
string htmlContent = "<html><body><h1>Hello world!</h1></body></html>";
wdRange.InsertAfter(htmlDoc);
```

The HTML is understood as text and not interpreted.
I have tried/considered using the Range.PasteSpecial() but did not succeed using the below code:

```
// Load the html into the clipboard
Clipboard.SetText(bkmContent);

// Attempt to insert at the end of the document
Range wdRange = doc.Range(doc.Characters.Count-1, doc.Characters.Count);
wdRange.PasteSpecial(WdPasteDataType.wdPasteHTML);

// Attempt to create a bookmark around the inserted text
doc.Bookmarks.Add("HTMLInsert", wdRange);
```

As a result the HTML is still not interpreted and I see the html instructions and the bookmark does not include the text.

Comment: HTML is not a "native" file format for MS Word. Word needs to use a converter to incorporate HTML in a document. Word's converters work with either a file or when pasting from the clipboard, so you've discovered the two built-in possibilities. What would also be possible is to convert the HTML to Word Open XML, then use the `Range.InsertXML` command to put it into the document. I don't know, there may already be libraries for that... Or you could build your own converter. Personally, I'd go with the clipboard... (FWIW as I recall the Word JS API does have the functionality, just FYI.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I insert HTML-Formatted Strings into a Microsoft Word Document using Visual Basic while preserving formatting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161519/how-do-i-insert-html-formatted-strings-into-a-microsoft-word-document-using-visu). Even though the Q is about VB the information also applies to C#. Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22798403/how-to-insert-a-piece-of-html-code-in-xml-word-document-and-not-die-trying might be interesting.